# elasticsearch/kibana and nested object array

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

I have some documents that I imagine like those:

```
{
timestamp: "2017-11-12T00:00:00",
samples: [
  {
     param: "Temperature",
     value: 76.3
  },
  {
     param: "Pressure",
     value: 12.3
  }
 ]
}
```

I'd like to plot temperature vs pressure. and even better, aggregate the temperature for pressure ranges (avg for pressure between 0-5, 5-10, 10-15, tc...) How can I do this?

I could have done this:

```
{
  timestamp: "2017-11-12T00:00:00",
  "Temperature": 76.3
  "Pressure": 12.3
}
```

but it is not really convenient because

- I can have thousands of fields like temperature or pressure
- I don't know the name of parameters a priori, therefore I cannot figure out how to make the mappings before inserting.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In demand since [March 2014](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1084) :(

Q:

> So can someone clarify this; In this post
>   (https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-4-beta-1-released) for
>   Kibana4beta1 it states that "Kibana 4 brings the power of
>   Elasticsearch's nested aggregations to the click of a mouse. " However
>   I'm unable to create any visualizations on documents with nested
>   objects. I've also made sure the nested objects in my index template
>   are marked as "nested". So is Kibana's support for nested aggregations
>   not the same as ES's support for nested objects? What am I missing?
>   Thanks.

A:

> I think they're using "nested" here to refer to grouping via multiple
>   fields, eg "aggregate by time then geo" (not "nested" as in its use in
>   the platform for "nested objects")

[kimchy](https://github.com/kimchy) (Elasticsearch's creator) commented on March 31, 2016

> hey, chiming in. I chatted to Rashid about this, and while I feel the
>   pain of users wanting to use Kibana for nested mappings, supporting it
>   in a more general manner (that might imply additional features in
>   Elasticsearch level itself) is the path forward that maintains the
>   flexibility we need to have in Kibana. While getting this suggested
>   change in might solve the short term problem of not supporting nested,
>   it will prove to be problematic down the road.
>
> I head and feel the need here for Kibana to support nested, but this
>   is one of those cases where if it is not obvious how it needs to be
>   solved, it is better to leave it unsolved until we have a solution
>   that feels natural. We definitely need to continue and explore that,
>   one of those, which we chatted in different places, is automatically
>   supporting nested (wrapping and so on) in ES itself.